# How we can Linked bitcoin address "A" to "A1, A2, A3" In automated process

Tags: laravel, blockchain, bitcoin, wallet

I am developing an exchange website with bitcoin and eth where i have a node running on my server.

I have generated an admin address. Ex. "A" from my node and i have also generated user addresses "A1" and "A2" from same node.

My Requirement is..If user depositing coin from external sources on his addresses A1 and A2 then that coin should directly goes to the admin wallet "A" not to the address A1 and A2. so hows it will be linked and work in backend?

As if i will transfer from A1 and A2 to A then it will charge the transaction fees and that i want to avoid. so please let me know how it can be linked internally so that it automatic goes to the admin wallet "A".

Please help me for sorting out this problem. will be very appreciated.

Thanks
Dinesh Pal

Answer (score -1):

You can dump private key of the address "A1" with the command `dumpprivkey` in hot wallet(node), and thereafter input this privkey into admins cold wallet with `importprivkey`. As result, funds, sent to A1, will be available instantly in the both wallets - hot(exchange) and cold (admin).

Other solution, if you would like send money only to admin's wallet (cold only): generate list of an addresses in the cold wallet, copy that list to hot nodes, and lets your script provides such addresses to a customers.

Comment: i just want to clarify that admin address "A" is not the cold wallet. Admin have hot wallet address with the name of "A" as in this example. and user have also hot wallet with there names like "A1" and "A2". so please let me know now how it can be done.